# Is $x^4 +15x +25$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Is $x^4 +15x +25$  irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

The Eisenstein criterion does not help because $5^2 \mid 25$. Which criterion can I use?

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $x^4 + 15x + 25$ is strictly positive and thus has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$. So if it is reducible we can write $x^4 + 15x + 25 = (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)$. Try to derive a contradiction from this.